# Download pdf using urllib?

Tags: python, pdf, urllib

I am trying to download a pdf file from a website using urllib. This is what i got so far:

```
import urllib

def download_file(download_url):
    web_file = urllib.urlopen(download_url)
    local_file = open('some_file.pdf', 'w')
    local_file.write(web_file.read())
    web_file.close()
    local_file.close()

if __name__ == 'main':
    download_file('http://www.example.com/some_file.pdf')
```

When i run this code, all I get is an empty pdf file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably, you should first check the HTTP response code (`getcode()`). This might provide some clue. If all is OK at http-level, we have to look elsewhere. Have you tried to download a PDF from an other source? Could you provide the real URL of the PDF for testing purposes?

Comment: To copy to a local file use urlretrieve

Answer (score 25):

Here is an example that works:

```
import urllib2

def main():
    download_file("http://mensenhandel.nl/files/pdftest2.pdf")

def download_file(download_url):
    response = urllib2.urlopen(download_url)
    file = open("document.pdf", 'wb')
    file.write(response.read())
    file.close()
    print("Completed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: As noted by shockburner, you need to use open("document.pdf", 'wb')

Comment: This can work in python3 as well. All you have to do is change `urllib2` to `urllib.requests` in both locations.

Comment: *`urllib.request` –No `s`

Answer (score 13):

Change `open('some_file.pdf', 'w')` to `open('some_file.pdf', 'wb')`, pdf files are binary files so you need the 'b'. This is true with pretty much any file that you can't open in a text editor.

Comment: I tried it, but it still don't work. When I try to open the pdf file, I get an error message saying that the file type is not supported or that the file is damaged.

Comment: Odd, it works for me. Even your original code works for me without the 'b'. Can you download the pdf in a browser and open it normally. If you can then you should also include you python and `urllib` version with `print urllib.__version__`. You might also want to try `urllib2` instead of `urllib`.

Comment: @user3774185 Take a look at the file with a web browser. It's most likely a HTML page with a captcha from the file hosting site you are trying to download from.

Comment: When I clicked URL I found on a website, it directly started downloading without loading me to another website. When I found the link in the HTML, pasted it in my a browser, I had to complete a CAPTCHA to download it.

Answer (score 7):

Try to use `urllib.retrieve` (Python 3) and just do that:

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

def download_file(download_url):
    urlretrieve(download_url, 'path_to_save_plus_some_file.pdf')

if __name__ == 'main':
    download_file('http://www.example.com/some_file.pdf')
```

Comment: from urllib.request import urlretrieve, request has typo :)

Comment: Thanks it helped me.

Answer (score 4):

The tried the above code, they work fine in some cases, but for some website with pdf embedded in it, you might get an error like **HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden**. Such websites have some server security features which will block known bots. In case of urllib it uses a header which will say something like ====> **python urllib/3.3.0**. So I would suggest adding a custom header too in request module of urllib as shown below.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen 
import requests  
url="https://realpython.com/python-tricks-sample-pdf"  
import urllib.request  
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})  
r = requests.get(url)

with open("<location to dump pdf>/<name of file>.pdf", "wb") as code:
    code.write(r.content)
```

Comment: This seems to no longer work, it doesn't work with this url for example: https://crsreports.congress.gov/product/pdf/R/R44900/6

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using following lines of code

```
import urllib.request
import shutil
url = "link to your website for pdf file to download"
output_file = "local directory://name.pdf"
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(output_file, 'wb') as out_file:
     shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI: You can also use wget to download url pdfs easily. Urllib versions keep changing and often cause issues (at least for me).

```
import wget

wget.download(link)
```

Instead of entering the pdf link, you can also modify your code such that you enter a webpage link and extract all pdfs from there. Here's a guide for that: https://medium.com/the-innovation/notesdownloader-use-web-scraping-to-download-all-pdfs-with-python-511ea9f55e48