# Python - Downloading with a List of Items

Tags: python, pandas, download, urllib2

I want to use the Python notebook to download several PDF files from a server. The only difference between all URLs is that they differ in one value. The URL scheme looks like:

```
http://file.server.com/content.asp?H=cat1&NR=123456&T=abc
```

The only value that changes is `NR=xxxxxx`

I have a *.csv file with all the different NRs

```
ID NR
1  123456
2  123457
3  123458
...
```

Regarding the code, I found [this thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844729/download-pdf-using-urllib) but just don't know how to implement an iteration through the csv/dataframe with the values.

```
import urllib2
```

<< Would be good to have a function here telling the script to wait each 5 seconds before the next download >>

```
def main():
    download_file("http://file.server.com/content.asp?H=cat1&NR=<<VARIABLE FROM CSV>>&T=abc")

def download_file(download_url):
    response = urllib2.urlopen(download_url)
    file = open("<<Store with ID name.pdf>>", 'w')
    file.write(response.read())
    file.close()
    print("Completed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `url` column with the variable value substituted:

```
In [254]:
url = r'http://file.server.com/content.asp?H=cat1&NR=123456&T=abc'
url

Out[254]:
'http://file.server.com/content.asp?H=cat1&NR=123456&T=abc'

In [256]:
df['url'] = url.split(r'&NR=')[0] + r'&NR=' + df['NR'].astype(str) + r'&T' + url.split(r'&T')[1]
df

Out[256]:
   ID      NR                                                url
0   1  123456  http://file.server.com/content.asp?H=cat1&NR=1...
1   2  123457  http://file.server.com/content.asp?H=cat1&NR=1...
2   3  123458  http://file.server.com/content.asp?H=cat1&NR=1...

In [258]:    
df['url'].iloc[0]

Out[258]:
'http://file.server.com/content.asp?H=cat1&NR=123456&T=abc'
```

You can then call `apply` on that column passing in your func:

```
df['url'].apply(download_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def buildNR(nr):
    return 'http://file.server.com/content.asp?H=cat1&NR={}&T=abc'.format(nr)

for line in csv.read():
    nr = extract_nr(line)
    download_file(buildNR(nr))
```

Just read the csv file and extrace the `NR` field.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the csv file line by line download the content by updating the url.
Code  :

```
import csv, sys
def download_file(download_url,id):
    response = urllib2.urlopen(download_url)
    file = open(id+".pdf", 'w')
    file.write(response.read())
    file.close()
    print("Completed")

filename = 'some.csv'
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    try:
        for row in reader:
            print row
            download_file("http://file.server.com/content.asp?H=cat1&NR="+row[1]+"&T=abc",row[1])
    except csv.Error as e:
        sys.exit('file %s, line %d: %s' % (filename, reader.line_num, e))
```

Comment: This one looks good, too. How would I add the "wait" function so that the script makes a short pause before the next download?

Comment: You are doing an IO operation via writing the data in the file. This operation itself will need some microseconds to execute. So you do not need any pause or sleep function. Also urlopen is called synchronously so unless it is executed 100% , next line will not be executed. Its like 100% serial. So adding sleep will only increase your execution time and make your CPU idle.

Comment: @Johnny please accept the answer if it works for the others to get benefit.