# Download pdf from https://xxxx/ShowDocument?id=yyyy in Python

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping

I'm new to web scraping, but pretty familiar with Python.  I'm trying to find a way to use Python to download the pdf (or one like it) at this link:

https://www.gilbertaz.gov/Home/ShowDocument?id=21298

I've seen code online ([Download pdf using urllib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844729/download-pdf-using-urllib)) for how to download a file with a known format such as http://www.example.com/mypdf.pdf for example.
However, this whole `ShowDocument?id=XXXXX` format is throwing me for a loop.  I'm guessing that this format is a pointer to a file structure on the website where the files are stored, but I don't know how to access/download these files.  Has anyone else seen this and know how to deal with it?

Comment: That's the format for a HTTP `GET` request, passing the value `XXXXX` for the argument `id`. ShowDocument is the handler script (or webpage) for this request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.gilbertaz.gov/Home/ShowDocument?id=21298'
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

with open('/tmp/metadata.pdf', 'wb') as fd:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size):
        fd.write(chunk)
```

Try this and see if it works. Otherwise, let me know.

Comment: Seems to work, thanks!  It's just missing a declaration of chunk_size, but I fixed that in my code.

Comment: Jed awesome! Glad to help